# I'm planning to visit the US on two different occasions. Do I need to provide documentation from both in order to get a visa?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens

I am an Indian citizen studying in UK (Tier 4). This summer, I am planning to attend a summer school and visit an academic collaborator in US. Both are different locations and the institutes are not related. I would like to apply for visa for my US trip. I have the following few questions:

1) What type of visa I should apply for ?

2) Do I ask for a letter from both places ? With different dates ?

3) Does it require me to provide details of my accommodation at both places ?

Comment: Both the schooling and the meeting with a collaborator are going to occur during the same trip to the US? Are they in different states (not really important, just curious)?

Comment: If you're trying to edit your post, please use your existing user account

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite clear how long you're staying and what exactly you're studying, but the [State Department](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/study-exchange/student.html#overview) breaks it down for you (emphasis mine)

> For short periods of recreational study, a Visitor (B) visa can be
>   used Enrollment in a short recreational course of study, which is not
>   for credit toward a degree or academic certificate, is permitted on a
>   **visitor (B) visa**.

However you're going to need an F visa if you're going to study somewhat more seriously, which I think is more likely based on the wording of your question.

> Another academic institution, including a language training program

For your other questions, any visa application will ask you to provide accommodation details so yes you should provide that as well as your invitation letters to demonstrate what the purpose of the trip is.